# CakePHP to CodeIgniter conversion

Tags: php, cakephp, codeigniter, frameworks

I want to convert an application from CakePHP to Code Igniter.  Has anyone tried to do this?  With my CakePHP application almost all the coding has been done in the controller layer, with the models pretty much exactly as they come out of baking.

Comment: why? for the sake of argument? What does CI provide that Cake doesn't?

Comment: There's no tool that does the conversion for you. I think you are going to have to write it all but since cakephp is more "magically", it should be less coding than CI.

Comment: @mhughes, I didn't want the question to turn into a Cake vs CI thread, there's lots on that.  I've made the decision to switch and now that I have, I wanted to know if others had tried it.

Comment: @icc97 can you share your experiences on how did you manage this conversion and what all things you learnt? Thanks.

Comment: @SaurabhHooda I never did it, I stayed with CakePHP and just accepted the slower performance. Given that there is nothing to migrate between the two, you could waste a lot of time. Better to try things like APC Cache first and see if it makes it acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CakePHP is newer, more feature rich and heavier than Code Igniter (CI is designed to have a much smaller footprint) so you will most likely find yourself creating functionality in CI to match cake's.

CakePHP also handles some core capabilities differently than CI. For example, routing functionality is handled via a dedicated class rather than per controller as in CI (via _remap).

I have never seen a tool that helps to automate such a conversion as it's rarely, if ever, done.

Taking all that into account, I believe the best approach is to rebuild your application from the ground up, drawing on your existing code and database schema.

Comment: Agreed.  I don't think you're going to be able to reuse a lot of code.  THat said, you can reuse most of the design and database schema, which in my mind is really valuable as well (I'm currently doing the same thing from Cake to Zend as an experiment to learn Zend by implementing a system that I already know really well).

Comment: thanks, I suspected that this might be the case. I was hoping someone might have tried it before me though.

Comment: @Travis Leleu, thanks also, I love to know what you find as a result of switching.